# Input group addon not aligning well on the mozilla browser

Tags: css, alignment, bootstrap-4

I have the following table:

```
<table class="neo-table">
  <tr>
    <td>Day of final discharge home</td>
    <td>{{ form_widget(form.mHomeDischargeDay, {'id': 'M_Home_discharge_day', 'attr':{'style':'width:60px'}})}}</td>
    <td><input type="button" value="enter date" onclick="convertDate('M_Home_discharge_day')"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td >Weight at final discharge</td>
    <td colspan="2"><div class="input-group">{{ form_widget(form.mHomeWeight, {'attr':{'style':'width:80px'}})}}<div class="input-group-addon">g</div> </div></td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td >Head circumference at final discharge</td>
    <td colspan="2"><div class="input-group">{{ form_widget(form.mHomeHeadCirc, {'attr':{'style':'width:80px'}})}}<div class="input-group-addon">cm</div> </div></td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Length at final discharge</td>
    <td colspan="2"><div class="input-group">{{ form_widget(form.mHomeLength, {'attr':{'style':'width:80px'}})}}<div class="input-group-addon">cm</div></div></td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Enteral feeding at final discharge</td>
    <td>{{ form_widget(form.mHomeFeeding)}}</td> 
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

On the chrome browser, it works fine and displays this:
[image: Chrome]
But on the mozilla browser, the group addon is not correctly aligned:
[image]

I tried adding this:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Like mentioned on this post:
[Input group addon alignment](http://%3Clink%20href=%22https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.3/css/bootstrap.min.css%22%20rel=%22stylesheet%22/%3E)

But I have not been able to figure out so far where I can fix this issue.

Edit:
Here is a simplified version of the problem:

```
<table style="width: 100%";>
  <tr>
    <td>row1 col1</td>
    <td>row1 col2</td>
    <td>row1 col3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td >row2 col1</td>
    <td colspan="2"><div class="input-group">row2 col2<div class="input-group-addon">row2 col2</div> </div></td> 
  </tr>
</table>
```

With the code above, I get the following result on mozilla:
[image: Addon]
I would like "row2 col2" to be in the immediate right vicinity of "row2col2"
What is the way to do this?

Comment: Can you post the rendered HTML instead of the template widgets?

Comment: ZimSystem, I updated the post. Does this help to understand the issue?

Comment: Does mozilla support input-group-addon?

Comment: That version of Bootstrap 4 is pretty ancient. You should check the 4.0.0 stable version!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by wrapping input group addons with divs as shown below:
It works fine for Chrome and Mozilla.

```
<table class="neo-table">
  <tr>
    <td>Day of final discharge home</td>
    <td>
        <div class="row" style='margin-bottom: 5px'>
        <div style='white-space: nowrap'> 
        <div class='col-xs-5'> 
          <div class='col-xs-2'>{{ form_widget(form.mHomeDischargeDay, {'id': 'M_Home_discharge_day', 'attr':{'style':'width:60px'}})}}</div>
        </div>
        </div>  
      </div>
  </td>
    <td><input type="button" value="enter date" onclick="convertDate('M_Home_discharge_day')"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Weight at final discharge</td>
    <td>   
        <div class="row" style='margin-bottom: 5px'>
            <div style='white-space: nowrap'>    
                <div class='col-xs-5'>
                    <div class='col-xs-2'><div class="input-group">{{ form_widget(form.mHomeWeight, {'attr':{'style':'width:80px'}})}}<div class="input-group-addon">g</div></div></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td>Head circumference at final discharge</td>
    <td>   
        <div class="row" style='margin-bottom: 5px'>
            <div style='white-space: nowrap'>    
                <div class='col-xs-5'>
                    <div class='col-xs-2'><div class="input-group">{{ form_widget(form.mHomeHeadCirc, {'attr':{'style':'width:80px'}})}}<div class="input-group-addon">cm</div></div></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td>Length at final discharge</td>
    <td>   
        <div class="row" style='margin-bottom: 5px'>
            <div style='white-space: nowrap'>    
                <div class='col-xs-5'>
                    <div class='col-xs-2'><div class="input-group">{{ form_widget(form.mHomeLength, {'attr':{'style':'width:80px'}})}}<div class="input-group-addon">cm</div></div></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr> 

    <tr>
    <td>Congenital malformation</td>
    <td>{{ form_widget(form.mBdefect)}}</td>
    <td colspan="3">{{ form_widget(form.mBdefectSpecific, {'attr':{'style':'width:250px'}})}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Enteral feeding at final discharge</td>
    <td>{{ form_widget(form.mHomeFeeding)}}</td> 
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```